# Why am I getting an EACCES error when trying to remove autopublish in MeteorJS 0.9?

Tags: meteor

Trying to perform a simple

```
meteor remove autopublish
```

and I receive an EACCES error.

```
    csellis@ubuntu:~/arrests$ meteor remove autopublish

/home/csellis/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.19qhb7r++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/main.js:1301
}).run();
   ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/csellis/arrests/.meteor/cordova-plugins'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:971:15)
    at _.extend.removeCordovaPlugins (/home/csellis/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.19qhb7r++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/project.js:973:8)
    at main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/home/csellis/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.19qhb7r++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands-packages.js:2087:11)
    at /home/csellis/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.19qhb7r++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/tools/main.js:1241:23
```

I don't know how to repair this bug.

Comment: try 'sudo' at start, may be

Comment: and if 'sudo' works, then `sudo chown` it to yourself